# Remove bibliography from a Wikipedia article

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm using this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features = "html.parser")

for t in soup.find_all(["script", "style"]):
    t.decompose()
for t in soup.find_all("div", class_ = "reflist"):
    t.decompose()
```

to remove uninteresting parts of a Wikipedia article.
How would you remove bibliography section from an arbitrary Wikipedia article (arbitrary language)?

Comment: Can you send more code? Currently, we only can see the for loops, which makes helping your problem much harder.

Comment: @TheUltimateGuide I edited the question. ulr may be for example [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_brain)

Comment: I suggest using [mwclient](https://mwclient.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead to directly talk to the MediaWiki API. It will be a way easier to grab the article data if you're scraping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the `bibliography` section from the article, see this example using a CSS Selector to select `bibliography`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_brain"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.select("h2:nth-of-type(12), ul cite"):
    # print(tag.text)
    tag.decompose()
```

---

**Edit:** For the scraper to work on all pages, search for a heading that contains `Bibliography`, remove it and the next `<ul>` elements:

```
for tag in soup.select("h2:contains('Bibliography'), h3:contains('Bibliography')"):
    ul = tag.find_next('ul')
    
    tag.decompose()
    ul.decompose()
```

Comment: This only works for that one particular page. On other pages e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy) it doesn't work.

Comment: This is better, but works only for english. I'm looking for something more general, to work for other languages as well. Of course, this may not be possible, so I will wait for some time yet (before accepting).